# How to use the Singular Inversion Theorem?

Tags: combinatorics, complex-analysis, singularity, analytic-combinatorics

> For $r \ge 2$ let $\mathcal{C}_r$ denote the class of Cayley trees in which every vertex has at most $r$ children. We denote the EGF of $\mathcal{C}_r$ by $C_r(z)$. Show that the Singular Inversion Theorem (see below) is applicable to $C_r(z)$ and use it to determine an asymptotic formula for $[z^n]C_r(z)$ in the case $r = 2$.

When I use the symbolic method, analogously to the case of general Cayley trees, to determine $C_r(z)$ I get: $\mathcal{Z} \times \text{SET}_{\le r}(\mathcal{Z})$, and thus:

$$C_r(z) = z \sum_{k=1}^r \frac{1}{k!} z^k = \sum_{k=1}^r \frac{1}{k!} z^{k+1}.$$

However, I already get stuck here as the $C_r(z)$ I computed does not fulfill the condition $C_r(0) \ne 0$.

Could you please tell me what I am doing wrong?

> **Singular Inversion Theorem**: Let $\phi(u)$ be analytic at $0$ and its series expansion $\phi(u) = \sum_{k} \phi_k u^k$ at $0$ satisfy the following conditions:
>
> 1. $\phi(0) \ne 0$
> 2. $[u^k]\phi(u) \ge 0 \quad (\forall k \ge 0)$
> 3. $[u^k]\phi(u) > 0  \text{ for some } k \ge 0$, i.e $\phi(u)$ is non-linear
> 4. The radius of convergence of $\sum_k \phi_k u^k$ is $R \in (0, \infty]$.
>
> If there exists a unique solution $u_0 \in (0,R)$ of the equation
> $$\phi(u) - u\phi^\prime(u) = 0, $$
> then the solution $u(z)$ of the equation $u(z) = z\phi(u(z))$ satisfies the following:
>
> 1. $u(z)$ is analytic at $0$
> 2. The dominant singularity of $u(z)$ is given by $\rho := \frac{u_0}{\phi(u_0)}$.
> 3. The singular expansion of $u(z)$ for $z \rightarrow \rho$ is of the form
>    $$u(z) = u_0 - \sqrt{ \frac{2 \phi(u_0)}{ \phi^{\prime\prime}(u_0) }} \biggl( 1- \frac{z}{\rho} \biggr)^{1/2} + \sum_{j \ge 2} C_j \biggl(1 + \frac{z}{\rho} \biggr)^{j/2}$$
> 4. If additionally $\phi$ is aperiodic, then
>    $$ [z^n]u(z) = \sqrt{ \frac{1}{2\pi} \frac{ \phi(u_0)}{ \phi^{\prime\prime} }} n^{-3/2} \rho^{-n} \cdot \bigg(1 + \mathcal{O}\bigg(\frac{1}{n}\bigg)\bigg).$$
>    **Remark**: Apparently this is a variant of the Singular Inversion Theorem described in Flajolet & Sedgewick p.404)